# How to fix Fortran type mismatch warning in important operational forecast code without breaking anything?

Tags: fortran

I am working on a library called NCEPLIBS-g2, a free and open source science library for dealing with meteorological data files in the GRIB2 format.

I am getting a warning from some code that I would like to fix. But this code is operational, and not super well tested, so I really need to be careful.

The warning is:

```
/home/ed/NCEPLIBS-g2/tests/test_gbytec.F90:122:24:

   39 |   call g2_sbytesc(out, in, iskip, nbits, nskip, n)
      |                       2 
......
  122 |   call g2_sbytesc(out4, r_in, iskip, nbits, nskip, num)
      |                        1
Warning: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (REAL(4)/INTEGER(4)).
```

The problem is we are calling g2_sbytesc() with a real array for the second parameter, but the subroutine expects an integer array:

```
subroutine g2_sbytesc(out, in, iskip, nbits, nskip, n)
  implicit none

  character*1, intent(out) :: out(*)
  integer, intent(in) :: in(n)
  integer, intent(in) :: iskip, nbits, nskip, n
```

Here's some test code, with comments, that explains what's happening:

```
  ! For this test to pass the -fallow-argument-mismatch flag must be
  ! used, because I am passing in a real array instead of an int array
  ! for the in parameter. This is how g2_sbytesc() is called in
  ! addfield.F90.
  print *, 'Testing g2_sbytesc() with a real array (size 1) instead of an int array...'
  iskip = 0
  nbits = 32
  nskip = 0
  num = 1
  r_in(1) = 1 
  call g2_sbytesc(out4, r_in, iskip, nbits, nskip, num)
  ! Note that the 32-bit IEEE representation of 1.0 is 3f800000. The
  ! decimal for 3f is 63, the decimal for 80 is 128.
  if (ichar(out4(1)) .ne. 63 .and. ichar(out4(2)) .ne. 128 .and. ichar(out4(3)) .ne. 0 .and. ichar(out4(4)) .ne. 0) stop 50
  ! print '(z2.2)', out4(1)  
  ! print '(z2.2)', out4(2)  
  ! print '(z2.2)', out4(3)  
  ! print '(z2.2)', out4(4)
```

So how do I fix this? Can I just copy the real array into an integer array and call the subroutine with an integer array? This seems good, but this code also has to work when compiled for 8-byte reals and 8-byte ints.

Comment: The error in your test case is different from the error in your original. The first set of warnings are simply that you call the same (non-generic) procedure twice with different arguments each time, not specifically because one of them is "wrong".

Comment: Yes, you fix this by providing correct arguments to the procedure. You can do that by changing your actual argument, using generics (possibly "templating hacks") using polymorphism, or assumed types. Some people are even fans of `transfer` for this.

Comment: Is your problematic procedure an entirely Fortran thing, or is the Fortran procedure an entry point/wrapper/interface for something in a language like C which is much less type fussy?

Comment: Finally, you needn't worry too much about your changes "breaking anything": as your compiler is telling you, it's already broken.

Comment: If this code "is operational and not well tested", hopefully no one's life is depending on it to give a correct answer.  From your description, it seems you need to provide a generic interface to select an appropriate procedure for `real(4)`, `integer(4)`, `real(8)`, and `integer(8)`.  (Yes, I know 4 and 8 are not portable).

Answer (score -1):

<strike>The comments in the code dive you the solution to suppress the warnings: use the `-fallow-argument-mismatch` option in your gfortran comman line (or similar option if another compiler).</strike> You can use the `-w` option on the gfortran command line to suppress the warnings.

Now, is it a good idea to hide the dust under the carpet? I depends. It's probably *never* a good idea, but it's not necessarily a stupid idea. This kind of argument mismatch was not rare in old Fortran codes, and it's actually harmless in practice to pass a real array to a routine that expects an integer array, **as long as one doesn't try passing values**, but rather just a memory area with an undefined content. The standard guarantees that a REAL has the exact same storage size as an INTEGER, so memory wise the mismatch is harmless (again, at least in practice).

Comment: `-fallow-argument-mismatch` doesn't suppress the warning. As can be seen in the first output, it downgrades the diagnostic from an error to a warning, which can then be suppressed using `-w`. The question seems to be asking _how_ to correct the code not whether it's safe to ignore the warning.

Comment: @francescalus my bad, I mixed up the options... Regarding the choice between fixing the problem or living with it,  it's IMO important to evaluate the severity of the problem before making an educated choice. Sometimes there are reasons (whether they are good or bad) why some codes use illegal tricks, and fixing them is not always straightforward.